# Best practice about the frequency of sentiment analysis in Azure Text Analytics

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-analytics

In my asp.net application, I want to do a sentiment analysis on each discussion forum item as they are posted by the users. I wonder if it is a good practice to make a request to Azure Text Analytics server to do a new Sentiment Analysis each time a text is posted by any user. Or, is it better to do this somehow once a day on all posts as a batch. I wonder what is the best practice about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on a similar project as you. My suggestion for your question is, you should select proper interval based on your requirement and need. For example, if you want to react based on the sentiment result of every post in a timely manner, you need to do a analysis every time you pull a new post. Also you can adjust your time interval of "pull and analyze" based on your business/ research need. IF you just want to train your model and predict something based on the data you get and you have no need for timely reaction, I think once a day is enough.

For our project, we are in the situation 1. So we will do a quick analysis when we receive any new post so that we can have a quick reaction.

Hope this helps.